# Why is my daughter eating paint?

Tags: toddler

Me and my wife recently moved into a new house and recently painted the walls. I have a two-year-old daughter and she started, EATING the paint. We don’t know why. We’ve tried disciplining her for this and taking her to a doctor. All have been inconclusive. I’m getting scared for her and i know its non-toxic paint but...
ITS STILL PAINT!

If anyone has any suggestions to make her stop or what might be going on please help us.

Comment: "We've tried disciplining her for this" What sort of discipline?

Comment: Taking away stuff and of course keeping her waway from walls

Comment: I don't understand how she can be eating paint. Usually individuals who eat paint pick it off the walls because it's chipping. New paint doesn't chip. How is she getting it off the walls?

Comment: She picks it off the walls where she can chip it or sometimes even licks the fresh paint.

Comment: It must taste nice. My friend had a daughter who, aged two, developed a liking for the salts that came out of a patch of plastered wall as it dried. It was just the height that she could lick it. She stopped when it was dry enough to have wallpaper added.

Answer (score 4):

Substitution, distraction and prevention are the tools that in my experience work with children that are 2yo.

One way to substitute, distract, and prevent, is to give your daughter a toy, for example a fabric book that includes textures and materials that are safe and exciting for young children.  For my kids we had a fabric book that had a page that crinkled and cracked as my kids flexed the fabric.  I don't know what was in the fabric page that made these sounds but with all of my kids is was a favorite.  So, if you observe your daughter and she's starting to go for the paint, you can substitute a toy that she finds exciting.

Another way to substitute, distract, and prevent is to get your daughter's attention and offer food while saying to her "this is food, we only eat food."  In this way you're setting an expectation that food is the only thing we eat, and you're offering her a small bit of food as an example.

To be clear, I'm not saying that she's hungry, only that she currently thinks that paint is something you eat, and this would be one way to work on correcting that.

With a 2yo child, you have the ability to control her environment, to prevent her from having access to the paint.

Her bed can be moved away from the wall so she can't lay in bed and pick at the paint.

If that doesn't prevent her from picking at the paint then you can block her access to the wall.

You could temporarily put fabric on the wall, and you'd likely have to install it so that she can't just move it aside to reach the paint.  One way to install the fabric would be to staple it to a board and then attach the board to the wall with the staples against the wall, so that she can't access the staples.  The fabric only has to cover the wall up to the height that she can reach, so maybe 1m up from the floor.  This might sound extreme, but it is one example of how you could temporarily modify the room where she sleeps or plays in a way the prevents her from eating the paint even when you are not in the the room with her.

The last suggestion I have is to consider the possibility that your daughter is going for the paint as a way to get your attention.  I'm not suggesting that she isn't getting enough attention, only that children sometimes repeat actions that they have learned will result in a parent's attention.  So, how you respond when she goes for the paint hmay be having an influence on whether or not she repeats that behavior.  The best response is to be as bland and boring and even, from her point if view, uninterested, because those reactions from you starve that behavior, which removes the motivation for her to repeat the behavior.

Likely, in the short term, you'll need to use multiple strategies to stop your daughter from eating paint.

Remeber, how our why your child decided to eat paint isn't as important as what you do to stop that behavior now.  How our why your daughter decided to eat paint wasn't caused by your parenting.  Kids sometimes do goofy things, because they're kids.  It's not much of an explanation, but having your child do something goofy is an experience that many parents share.

Answer (score 1):

This might be pica.  Talk to your pediatrician!

Answer (score 0):

At 2yo, the why is probably curiosity, the texture, the taste, etc... ie. just exploring her world.

If she's chowing down in a specific area, or if you can tell where she's headed for her next snack, you might could try to make the area less appetizing.  Try spraying it with lemon juice just before she chomps down.

There's a thing called "pica" where kids eat non-food items, but I would have expected her doctor to consider that.  Sometimes they will eat things if their bodies are missing a nutrient and they are instinctively scavenging trying to find it (ie. iron deficiency is a common culprit).  Read-up on it and maybe ask the Dr. about it.  A blood test can determine if she's anemic.

Good luck!

Comment: [Pica is not caused by a nutritional deficiency](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4270917/) - that's a myth. It may well result in a nutritional deficiency, however.